# change __slots__ dynamically

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm working on a class that needs to be given it's `__dict__` attribute via `__init__` injection like this:

```
class Torrent(Model):
    def __init__(self, d):
        super(Torrent, self).__init__('torrents')
        self.__dict__ = d
```

And need to make sure not to change the structure of the object because the instance is going to end up in a NOSQL db. I thought that `__slots__` could be helpful, but I need to define it dynamically.

Is there a way to make it possible without a metaclass ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a factory function:

```
def GetTorrentClass(slots_iterable):
    class Torrent(object):
        __slots__ = slots_iterable
    return Torrent
```

Note that in order to use slots:

- `slots_iterable` must be an iterable of strings
- Your class must be new-style
- Your class can't inherit a class that implements `__dict__` (ie. that is not `__slots__` only)

Now, you say you 'need to make sure not to change the structure of the object', using `__slots__` is not the only (and probably not the best either) solution to your issue: using slots makes your class harder to use in code.

Instead, you could do the following:

```
class Torrent(object):
    def __init__(self, fields):
        self.fields = fields #Fields could be ('field1', 'field2')

    def save(self):
        for field in self.fields:
            self.store_to_db(field, getattr(self, field))
```

This way, you're sure that only your actual fields will be saved to your db.

Comment: I need to make the fields accessible from the code in a more natural way like torrent.some_field = some_val, thanks for the help.

Comment: If you don't use `__slots__`, you can *always* use `torrent.some_field = some_val`. You'll only need to set `some_field` in your `fields` variable when you instantiate the class (Or it could be a class variable too, and you could use a factory function if you need more variability).

Comment: setting an attribute torrent.some_field from fields sounds and it's more code, but the gainings in speed would justify the extra work.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean there. Here, the `fields` variable's only use is for the save method to recognize what fields it is supposed to save to the db.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the magic you require.

```
def construct_slots(slots):
    class SlotClass(object):
        __slots__ = slots
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            for slot, arg in zip(SlotClass.__slots__, args):
                setattr(self, slot, arg)
            for key, value in kwargs:
                setattr(self, key, value)
    return SlotClass

Torrent = construct_slots(("a",'b','c'))
a = Torrent(1,2,3)
print a.a
print a.b
```

Answer (score 0):

`__slots__` and `__dict__` are usually alternatives. In neither case will a metaclass help you dynamically create them for an instance, except that a custom metaclass can relax the restriction on assignment to `__dict__` (Django already does this).