# Dynamically adding __slots__ to an imported class

Tags: python, python-2.7

Take the following example:

```
from foo import Bar

b = Bar
print(b.__slots__)
#Stack trace, no attribute __slots__
```

Assume then that we want to add a `__slots__` attribute because lots (and lots) of `Bar` instances will be created.

```
from foo import Bar

CBar = Bar
CBar.__slots__ = ["one", "two", "three"]

b = CBar
print(b.__slots__)
#Success

b.four = 0
print(b.four)
#Prints 0....hmmm....
```

Is it possible to import a class from a module and add `__slots__` attribute dynamically?

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but it would surprise me greatly if you were able to swap out `__dict__`s for `__slots__`s at runtime, if only because of the magic involved in making that distinction.

Comment: @AdamSmith is correct (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10822309/429982) for some limitations on using `__slots__`).  That doensn't mean you can't create a brand new class though that mostly acts like `Bar`, but does have a `__slots__` on it (but it might require a bit of effort :))

Comment: As of Python 3.3, [instances of the same class will use a shared dict](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/), so using `__slots__` as a memory saving technique becomes less useful.

Comment: I know, that the link leads to a question regarding `__slots__` in Python 3, but answer by Martijn Pieters applies to Python 2.7 as well

Comment: @Alik I went ahead and marked as a duplicate as the linked answer does pertain to 2.x as well.  Can the 2.x tag be added to that question so it pops on a search / question start?